Sony CXD5605 Datasheet & Reference Schematic
I'm trying to find a proper datasheet with a reference schematic for the Sony CXD5605 or CXD5610 GNSS IC. They don't have anything published on their website.

Just go to https://www.sony-semicon.com/en/products/lsi-ic/gps.html. Go to product section and submit request for the datasheet for your preferred device by providing your details. You will receive the link in mail.
